# Selecting between time interval and length of channel

Tags: go, channel

I'm here to find out the most idiomatic way to do the follow task.

**Task**:

Write data from a channel to a file.

**Problem**:

I have a channel `ch := make(chan int, 100)`

I need to read from the channel and write the values I read from the channel to a file. My question is basically how do I do so given that

1. If channel `ch` is full, write the values immediately
2. If channel `ch` is not full, write every 5s.

So essentially, data needs to be written to the file at least every 5s (assuming that data will be filled into the channel at least every 5s)

Whats the best way to use `select`, `for` and `range` to do my above task?

Thanks!

Comment: When you do a write (either in case 1 or 2), do you want to write just a single `int` value from the channel, or you want to write the full content of the channel (to empty its buffer)?

Comment: Ah thanks for asking. I want to write the full contents i.e. empty its buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such "event" as *"buffer of channel is full"*, so you can't detect that [*]. This means you can't idiomatically solve your problem with language primitives using only 1 channel.

<sup>[*] Not entirely true: you could detect if the buffer of a channel is full by using `select` with `default` case when *sending* on the channel, but that requires logic from the senders, and repetitive attempts to send.</sup>

I would use another channel from which I would receive as values are sent on it, and "redirect", store the values in another channel which has a buffer of 100 as you mentioned. At each redirection you may check if the internal channel's buffer is full, and if so, do an immediate write. If not, continue to monitor the "incoming" channel and a timer channel with a `select` statement, and if the timer fires, do a "regular" write.

You may use `len(chInternal)` to check how many elements are in the `chInternal` channel, and `cap(chInternal)` to check its capacity. Note that this is "safe" as we are the only goroutine handling the `chInternal` channel. If there would be multiple goroutines, value returned by `len(chInternal)` could be outdated by the time we use it to something (e.g. comparing it).

In this solution `chInternal` (as its name says) is for internal use only. Others should only send values on `ch`. Note that `ch` may or may not be a buffered channel, solution works in both cases. However, you may improve efficiency if you also give some buffer to `ch` (so chances that senders get blocked will be lower).

```
var (
    chInternal = make(chan int, 100)
    ch         = make(chan int) // You may (should) make this a buffered channel too
)

func main() {
    delay := time.Second * 5
    timer := time.NewTimer(delay)
    for {
        select {
        case v := <-ch:
            chInternal <- v
            if len(chInternal) == cap(chInternal) {
                doWrite() // Buffer is full, we need to write immediately
                timer.Reset(delay)
            }
        case <-timer.C:
            doWrite() // "Regular" write: 5 seconds have passed since last write
            timer.Reset(delay)
        }
    }
}
```

If an immediate write happens (due to a "buffer full" situation), this solution will time the next "regular" write 5 seconds after this. If you don't want this and you want the 5-second regular writes be independent from the immediate writes, simply do not reset the timer following the immediate write.

An implementation of `doWrite()` may be as follows:

```
var f *os.File // Make sure to open file for writing

func doWrite() {
    for {
        select {
        case v := <-chInternal:
            fmt.Fprintf(f, "%d ", v) // Write v to the file
        default: // Stop when no more values in chInternal
            return
        }
    }
}
```

We can't use `for ... range` as that only returns when the channel is closed, but our `chInternal` channel is not closed. So we use a `select` with a `default` case so when no more values are in the buffer of `chInternal`, we return.

### Improvements

#### Using a slice instead of 2nd channel

Since the `chInternal` channel is only used by us, and only on a single goroutine, we may also choose to use a single `[]int` slice instead of a channel (reading/writing a slice is much faster than a channel).

Showing only the different / changed parts, it could look something like this:

```
var (
    buf = make([]int, 0, 100)
)

func main() {
    // ...

    for {
        select {
        case v := <-ch:
            buf = append(buf, v)
            if len(buf) == cap(buf) {
            // ...
    }
}

func doWrite() {
    for _, v := range buf {
        fmt.Fprintf(f, "%d ", v) // Write v to the file
    }
    buf = buf[:0] // "Clear" the buffer
}
```

#### With multiple goroutines

If we stick to leave `chInternal` a channel, the `doWrite()` function may be called on another goroutine to not block the other one, e.g. `go doWrite()`. Since data to write is read from a channel (`chInternal`), this requires no further synchronization.

Comment: If data enters `ch` at one int every 2 seconds, then the first case will be executed 5 times (total 10s). But we need to write every five seconds.

Comment: @VarunPatro If data enters `ch` in every 2 seconds, yes, first case will be executed in every 2 seconds, **but write will not happen** only if buffer of `chInternal` is full (see the `if` statement), but it won't be full, so the first write will only happen after 5 seconds (as it should) when `timer` fires.

Comment: Thanks @icza! Looks really comprehensive including the doWrite method (didn't think of using default..)

Comment: @VarunPatro Added alternatives how to improve it. You may even replace the 2nd channel with a slice, that way the `doWrite()` function also becomes simpler.

Answer (score 0):

if you just use 5 seconds write, to increase the file write performance,
you may fill the channel any time you need,
then writer goroutine writes that data to the buffered file,
see this very simple and idiomatic sample without using timer
with **just using for...range**:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func WriteToFile(filename string, ch chan int) {
    f, e := os.Create(filename)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    w := bufio.NewWriterSize(f, 4*1024*1024)
    defer wg.Done()
    defer f.Close()
    defer w.Flush()
    for v := range ch {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%d ", v)
    }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 100)
    wg.Add(1)
    go WriteToFile("file.txt", ch)

    for i := 0; i < 500000; i++ {
        ch <- i // do the job
    }
    close(ch) // Finish the job and close output file
    wg.Wait()
}
```

and notice the `defer`s order.

and in case of 5 seconds write, you may add one interval timer just to flush the buffer of this file to the disk, like this:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func WriteToFile(filename string, ch chan int) {
    f, e := os.Create(filename)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    w := bufio.NewWriterSize(f, 4*1024*1024)

    ticker := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second)
    quit := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                if w.Buffered() > 0 {
                    fmt.Println(w.Buffered())
                    w.Flush()
                }
            case <-quit:
                ticker.Stop()
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    defer wg.Done()
    defer f.Close()
    defer w.Flush()
    defer close(quit)
    for v := range ch {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%d ", v)
    }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 100)
    wg.Add(1)
    go WriteToFile("file.txt", ch)

    for i := 0; i < 25; i++ {
        ch <- i // do the job
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
    }
    close(ch) // Finish the job and close output file
    wg.Wait()
}
```

here I used `time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second)` for interval timer with `quit` channel, you may use `time.AfterFunc()` or `time.Tick()` or `time.Sleep()`.

with some optimizations ( removing quit channel):

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func WriteToFile(filename string, ch chan int) {
    f, e := os.Create(filename)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    w := bufio.NewWriterSize(f, 4*1024*1024)
    ticker := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second)
    defer wg.Done()
    defer f.Close()
    defer w.Flush()

    for {
        select {
        case v, ok := <-ch:
            if ok {
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "%d ", v)
            } else {
                fmt.Println("done.")
                ticker.Stop()
                return
            }
        case <-ticker.C:
            if w.Buffered() > 0 {
                fmt.Println(w.Buffered())
                w.Flush()
            }
        }
    }
}
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 100)
    wg.Add(1)
    go WriteToFile("file.txt", ch)

    for i := 0; i < 25; i++ {
        ch <- i // do the job
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
    }
    close(ch) // Finish the job and close output file
    wg.Wait()
}
```

I hope this helps.