# is len(channel) in Go thread-safe?

Tags: go, thread-safety, channel

A channel can potentially be used by multiple Go routines. Is getting the length of the channel by using len(channel) from some of the Go routines thread-safe?

Comment: Yes, but it's usually not useful since the value may change immediately after you read it

Comment: Related: [Selecting between time interval and length of channel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430186/selecting-between-time-interval-and-length-of-channel).

Answer (score 5):

It kind of depends on your use case

it is indeed safe to call, but the result cannot be trusted when other goroutines are sending / taking from that channel